# Convert data attribute google map cordinates from string to number?

Tags: javascript

I am retrieving google map coordinates from a data-attribute as a string but unsude how to convert them to numbers so I can pass them into the google maps `LatLng` method. Can anyone advise how I can achieve this?

Currently I receive the following info `40.7378732,-73.98873779999997` from data-coords, I thought parseInt would resolve this but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. It'll return an array.

```
var str = '40.7378732,-73.98873779999997';
var latLngArray = str.split(',').map(parseFloat); //[40.7378732,-73.98873779999997]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseFloat

Can't tell from your question, but if aren't you will also want to `split()` the string

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit